# In jQuery is there way for slideDown() method to scroll the page down too?

Tags: jquery

The [`slideDown()`](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) applied to a `div` element does the slide down, but doesn't scroll the page down and the `div` slided down `div` remains hidden from view.

Is there a way to scroll the page down as well so the user can view the `div`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quick demo [here](http://jsbin.com/agahi)

Basically all you need is

```
 $('html, body').animate({ 
      scrollTop: $('#yourDiv').offset().top 
  }, 3000);
```

Comment: Yeah that seems to work. But if clicked again it gives the page a jerk and tries to animate again. Is there a way to check if the div is already visible and not animate?

Comment: but maybe better as another Q!

Comment: @Daud: fast jumping confuses users. Animated scrolling is better usability. [This plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) also doesn't do scrolling when element is already visible...

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that shows how to use this solution with the complete callback of `slidedown`: http://jsfiddle.net/98ah2/3/

Answer (score 8):

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    inView: function(a) {
        var st = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop),
            ot = $(a).offset().top,
            wh = (window.innerHeight && window.innerHeight < $(window).height()) ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
        return ot > st && ($(a).height() + ot) < (st + wh);
    }
});

if ($('#whatever').is(':not(:inView)')) {
    $('html,body').animate({ 
         scrollTop: $('#whatever').offset().top 
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in a generic jQuery plugin that does animated scrolling (and also doesn't scroll at all when elements are visible) http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html It's similar to *scrollTo* plugin but is simpler (thus faster)