# jQuery scroll to child element after slideDown parent

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, slidedown

Let's say I've got a list of Titles:

```
<ul id="Titles-list>
  <li class="title">Title1</li>
  <li class="title">Title2</li>
  <li class="title">Title3</li>
</ul>
```

Below the titles I've got a div which contains more info:

```
<div>
   <h1>Descriptions</h1>
   <div class="content" style="display:none">
     <ul id="Descriptions-list">
       <li id="Title1">This is a description of Title1.</li>
       <li id="Title2">This is a description of Title2.</li>
       <li id="Title3">This is a description of Title3.</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, as you can see, the .content div is not displayed by default. What I need, is a script that will:

1. be triggered when I click on an item on the Titles-list
2. slideDown the .content to display the Descriptions-list
3. when the list is visible, scroll to the matching description.

I have tried this, but I couldn't get it to work: [In JQuery is there way for slideDown() method to scroll the page down too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472930/in-jquery-is-there-way-for-slidedown-method-to-scroll-the-page-down-too)

The script that I've written so far (doesn't work):

```
 $(".title").bind("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            title = $this.text();

        $(".content").slideDown(200, scroll($('#' + title).offset().top));

        function scroll (position) {
            $('html, body').delay('200').animate({
                scrollTop: position
            }, 200);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you show your js code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way that works:

```
$(".title").bind("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            title = $this.text();
            content = $(".content");
if(content.css("display")=="none"){
        $(".content").slideDown();
        $this.click();
} else{
   scroll($('#' + title).offset().top);
}

        function scroll (position) {
            $('html, body').delay('200').animate({
                scrollTop: position
            }, 200);
        }
    });
```

Basically, when user clicks on a Title and the Descriptions content is not displayed the script will reveal it and generate another click. The function will be called again, but this time the content will be already visible, so the function can scroll down to the matching description.